# c++ multidimensional array layout on stack and on heap

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

on stack:

```
string array3d1[x][y][z];
```

as far as I know, internally on the stack it's actually a one dimensional array.

on heap:

```
string * * * array3d2;
array3d2 = new string * * [x];
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    array3d2[i] = new string * [y];
    for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
    {
        array3d2[i][j] = new string [z];
    }
}
```

on heap it's array of array of array.

Questions:

(1) what's the index of array3d1[a][b][c] ?

(2) when I use below syntax to access array3d1 and array3d2:

```
array3d1[a][b][c];
```

and

```
array3d2[a][b][c];
```

how does the compiler know the right element to access since they are in different layout?

Comment: On the heap you have decided to make an array of pointers, each pointer pointing to an array of pointers, each of which point so an array. But you could have instantiated a real 3D array on the heap too.

Comment: juanchopanza, how to do a real 3d array on heap?

Comment: `int (*array3d)[y][z] = new int[x][y][z]`

Comment: How are you de-allocating this thing? That looks pretty intense.

Comment: @tadman `delete [] array3d;`

Comment: @tadman The catch is that `y` and `z` need to be compile-time constants.

Comment: This looks like a gigantic mess to manage. Why not just emulate a three dimensional array? Allocate `x*y*z` slots, write accessors like `get(x,y,z)` or `set(x,y,z)` to manage it. That'll be a lot faster than triple de-referencing a pointer. You could even preserve the `array[x][y][z]` semantics with some clever use of intermediate objects that have valid `[]` operator methods.

Comment: @tadman Yes, that would be the way to do it in real life code (except the [] access requires some proxy messiness which is hardly ever worth it, a plain `operator()(size_t, size_t, size_t)` lets you access elements via `array(x, y, z)`. I was trying to make the point that pointers to pointers to pointers aren't really multi-dimensional arrays, and you rarely need the data to be scattered all over the place anyway.

Comment: By the way, the `stack` and `heap` are irrelevant here.  The data is stored the way you declared it, regardless of the memory region.

Comment: @tadman overloading operator[] can only do [a,b,c], but not [a][b][c], right?

Comment: @rick As others have said, you can make it do that with a lot of proxy duct-tape, something best avoided. The `a,b,c` method is far, far more efficient since it requires just one computation and memory reference. The other requires *at least* three reads to get the final value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. *what's the index of array3d1[a][b][c]?*

   If you mean what is the value of `&array3d1[a][b][c] - (string*)array3d1`, it's equal to `a*y*z + b*z + c`.
2. *how does the compiler know the right element to access since they are in different layout?*

   The compiler knows, because `array3d1` and `array3d2` have different types.

   `array3d1` has type `array of size x of arrays of size y of arrays of size z of string`, so `array3d1[a]` has the type `array of size y of arrays of size z of string` and is located at `a`th index of original array, that is `a*y*z` `string*`s from its beginning. And so on other indices are applied.

   `array3d2` has type `pointer to pointer to pointer to string`, and indexing is done accordingly.